# sed the string and hold the value in new variable

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have this String `cap/media/101/101.mp4` and I need to cut the `101` in another Variable.

I am trying to do it with `sed` but it's not giving me the output I need.

```
echo cap/media/101/101.mp4 | sed -e 's/d/\(.*\)/\1/'
```

can someone please give an idea about it?

Comment: I am confused. Your `echo`ed string doesn't relate to your `101` thing and your `sed` expression doesn't make sense. What's the actual input and output that you want?

Comment: @zanna, sorry that was my mistake.

Comment: no problem, but I still don't quite understand your challenge - which part of the string do you want to keep? The part between the last `/` and `.mp4`, or a number between `/` and `/`, or something else? Because at the moment I would suggest `var=101`. Maybe you could add some more examples? I assume you are not just doing this on one string.

Comment: @Zanna, yes i have a txt file with Multiple line with similar kind of string in it.
and I would need to cut the part which is after media/ `101` / ;

Comment: please could you give a larger input and output sample so we can see what you want? :)

Comment: I need to hold this 101 not the 101.mp4 into a Variable.

Comment: is the part you want always after `/media/` or always before the last `/`? Is it always `101`?

Comment: no that is not always 101, this is incrementing like 101, 102 and so on. probabaly till 100000.

but the Media and the Last / is always same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the characters between `media/` and the next `/` (based on what you said in the comments) you could cut that part with

```
sed -r 's|.*media/([^/]+).*|\1|'
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` use ERE (so we don't have to escape `()` or `+` to use them as metacharacters
- `s|old|new|` replace `old` with `new` (using an alternative delimiter to avoid having to escape `/` in the string)
- `([^/]+)` save some characters that are not `/`
- `\1` the saved pattern (the rest is discarded)

Comment: @kunal always a pleasure

Comment: I am using this Sed Command Into the Bash script and can you please tell me how can i hold the value of after Sed into varibale

Comment: hmm could you paste your script into your questions or at http://paste.ubuntu.com ? @kunal

Comment: I have pasted it

Comment: we will need the exact link though

Comment: sorry, There is it http://paste.ubuntu.com/23954685/

Comment: @kunal I have to go to work now - I will look later but maybe edit your question with the script and details so someone else can fix it for you (or ask a new question linking to this one if you prefer)

Comment: Thank you anyway for your time and help. I will maybe make a new Thread.

thank again

Comment: @kunal any time all the best with it :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming consistent fields, a simple awk command can do the trick:

```
echo cap/media/101/101.mp4 | awk -F"/" '{print $3}'
```

Output:

```
101
```

Answer (score 1):

(Late to the party :)). So many ways to skin this cat...Here are a few:

Here, i am getting the digits surrounded by `/`:

With `cut`:

```
cut -d/ -f3
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -Po '/\K\d+(?=/)'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -F/ -lane 'print $F[2]'
```

With `python`:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; i=sys.stdin.read().split("/"); print(i[2])'
```

Another `sed`:

```
sed -E 's#.*/([0-9]+)/.*#\1#'
```

Another `awk` (though the already provided `awk` answer getting the `/` delimited 3rd field should be the way to go):

```
awk '{i=gensub(".*/([0-9]+)/.*", "\\1", "g"); print i}'
```

With `go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "cap/media/101/101.mp4"
    fmt.Println(strings.Split(str, "/")[2])
}
```

**Example:**

```
% cut -d/ -f3 <<<'cap/media/101/101.mp4'                                                          
101

% grep -Po '/\K\d+(?=/)' <<<'cap/media/101/101.mp4'
101

% perl -F/ -lane 'print $F[2]' <<<'cap/media/101/101.mp4'                                         
101

% python3 -c 'import sys; i=sys.stdin.read().split("/"); print(i[2])' <<<'cap/media/101/101.mp4'
101

% sed -E 's#.*/([0-9]+)/.*#\1#' <<<'cap/media/101/101.mp4'
101

% awk '{i=gensub(".*/([0-9]+)/.*", "\\1", "g"); print i}' <<<'cap/media/101/101.mp4'
101

## Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/kGdzyywEB2
```